# 2020 intel MBP bootlooping but still boots into windows

Tags: startup

I've reset PRAM and the SMC mutliple times. Have also revived the T2 chip. The machine bootloops if you try to: start it in MacOS, enter recovery mode, reinstall the os from a bootable drive or enter diagnostics mode. You can still boot into windows with 0 issues using the bootloader but if you select either the reinstall drive or macOS it just goes back to bootlooping.

IDK what I'm missing here. Thing has been set up to dual boot from the day I got it with no issues. Problem started the other day out of nowhere when I tried to flip back over to mac from windows and it started bootlooping instead.

Comment: This could be hardware because recovery and diagnostics are totally separate from regular macOS. Mac might have a driver that windows doesn’t load and that driver might be trying to load bad hardware

Comment: What do you mean by “revived the T2 chip?”  The recovery mode, was that Internet Recovery?

Comment: Hoping it isnt hardware bc I'm a college student so I'd rather spend days troubleshooting than spend money on a repair lol. If it was the driver issue you describe, how would I address that?

Comment: Can you clarify by responding to the questions asked eith an [edit]?  That will give us a better picture.  Also, confirm Internet Recovery Mode was attempted as that will remove local storage from the equation